# Confusion using path, multiple versions of python on mac osx

Tags: python, macos

I'm new to using terminal for python. And I am struggling to understand this environment after installing sublimetext to test and develop codes conveniently.

Below is one question. If I command the following,

```
echo $PATH
```

Returns,
`/usr/local/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

It seems like I have python 3.5 and I want to completely remove it since I only want 2.7 on my osx. If I check the version of python using -V, it returns 2.7. Further from the following command,

```
open ~/.bash_profile
```

Returns,

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH

export PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

I don't seem to have 3.5 anywhere. I was recommended to check path environment to remove whatever bits left of 3.5 python but I can't. I seem to be missing a lot of something I can't figure on my own. I would appreciate some experts' advise..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `python3` is the executable to run Python 3. Don't mess with the PATH too much because you could change the System installed Python

Comment: And you only need a single `/usr/local/bin` in the PATH. ;)

Comment: Thanks so much for your input, I still am not sure with the PATH. Yes, I had let someone else edit it while I didn't quite understand how to set it up. Can I request kind explanation as to what : is in these lines?

Comment: That character is a divider between each individual directory to search

Comment: Thank you. So in your opinion, no other directory must be searched than /usr/local/bin ?

Comment: Entirely depends on where you installed Python... All I was saying is that if you split your PATH variable on the colon character, look at how many times you repeat the same directory

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to uninstall Python 3; it coexists with Python 2 with no interference.

The last `export PATH=...` statement compiletely overrides all of the previous ones. You don't need to explicitly export `PATH` at all from your personal settings anyway, because the system alseady does this. The multiple additions of `/usr/local/bin` are obviously redundant.

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
```

would fix the problems and allow the Ruby uninstaller to remove itself at a later time (so I left in the useless `export` there in case it looks for that when removing itself).

Comment: So it conflicts with the comment from another user (cricket_007) in that I need to save the rest in the path, ':/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin', could I ask for explanation as to why?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand which comment you are alluding to. [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38815855/confusion-using-path-multiple-versions-of-python-on-mac-osx/38817413?noredirect=1#comment64999037_38815855) merely says that there are the redundant repetitions; [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38815855/confusion-using-path-multiple-versions-of-python-on-mac-osx/38817413?noredirect=1#comment64999000_38815855) is basically saying don't mess with things you don't understand, but I don't see how that would be in conflict with my answer.

Comment: Per the first comment where it is suggested to leave only '/usr/local/bin' in the PATH - my understanding was that it's not the same with leaving PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin. Aren't the two different ? But you are saying that they aren't quite conflicting?

Comment: Based on what I perceived right, I deleted the redundant /usr/local/bin: as it was typed twice in the path, but left the rest because I wasn't sure about the rest. I don't know how /usr/bin, /bin/, /usr/sbin, /sbin differ from one another..

Comment: They are different paths.  Originally, `/usr` was a separate partition which was only mounted later in the boot process, so you could not keep essential commands there, but because the partition was typically bigger, you wanted nonessential commands there.  `bin` vs `sbin` was originally for dynamically vs statically linked binaries IIRC, though you also see "mortal" vs "system" (i.e. privileged only) commands split between the two. But all you really need to know is that there are binaries you might need in all of them.

Comment: I would recommend you check with the command `which -a python python3` all the python versions that are installed on your system.

Comment: Except use the POSIX-mandated `type` instead of `which`; the latter exists in multiple versions with different behaviors, bugs, and compatibility concerns.